# XCode C++ assert re-definition not allowed by compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, llvm

I am porting some C++ codebase from Windows VC10 to Mac XCode 10.7 .I have a macro which wraps the "assert()" .The Microsoft compiler has no problem with the  following definition:

```
void assert(bool result, const char *call, const char *file, int line);
/// Wraps \c assert().//
#define MY_ASSERT(call) (mynsp::assert((call), #call, __FILE__, __LINE__))
```

while XCode throws me an error :
 *Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation*

Being complete noob to OS X and LLVM my question is how to work around this issue?

Btw, assert() declaration is wrapped with custom namespace (mynsp)

Comment: Works fine with G++. How many arguments do you pass to the macro?

Comment: Do you have `<cassert>` included somewhere?

Comment: No I don't have.Should I?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Probably some other header does. This is one of the reasons why macros suck.

Comment: `assert` is the name of a macro defined in `<cassert>`; I suggest you use a different name for your function. Either that will solve your problem, or at least prevent WTF moments for people reading your code. When I see `assert` in code, I simply assume it's the standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard header `<cassert>` (or `<assert.h>` in C) defines `assert` as a macro, making that name unusable for any other purpose. Even if you don't include that header yourself, it's possible that it's included indirectly from some other header. That is probably why you only see the problem on one platform, not both.

The best option is to rename your function to avoid the clash; alternatively, you could use `#undef assert` in any file that wants to use the name for your purpose.

Comment: Indeed,it was just a matter of changing the name.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on `assert` in your prototype and choose "Jump to Definition". You'll see that it's #define'd somewhere, causing this problem for you.

You could `#undef assert` to get past it.